# How can I ungzip a file and send it in response in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib

I have endpoint where I just serve a file by it's name. The file has .gz format so I have to unzip it before sending in response.

This is a part of the code:

```
const unzip = zlib.createGunzip();
const rs = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
rs.pipe(unzip).pipe(response);
```

And with this code I'm getting the size of the file in a browser but it doesn't start downloading, repeats GET request on server and eventually throws an error.

If I remove `.pipe(unzip)` and just leave it as `rs.pipe(response)` it serves the file but (obviously) unzipped.

Could you please point out on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of object/stream is `response` in your question? If it's a native node [`http.ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse), you'll still need to write the HTTP headers first, perhaps with [`response.writeHead`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers).

There's an [official example](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_compressing_http_requests_and_responses) (albeit reversed, compressing the HTTP response instead of decompressing it) in the zlib documentation page. It uses the `pipeline` function from the node streams API instead of just `.pipe` but it should give you a good model to follow. Refer to the server bit near the bottom for the `writeHead` followed by the `pipeline`:

```js
  /* ... */ {
    response.writeHead(200, { /* whatever headers you need here */ });
    pipeline(raw, zlib.createGzip(), response, onError);
  }
```

Does this help?

Comment: Your variant also works but the problem was in the fact that the file I wanted to serve was encrypted using 'crypto' module. So I had to decrypt it before serving like this `rs.pipe(decrypt).pipe(unzip).pipe(response);` How to serve an encrypted file I don't know and I don't need it actually. Thank you for the answer. I think I should've given more info about my program